# Using PHP how do I convert an array into a string of items for use in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I need to grab a load of arrays that I am fetching in an array using a loop ie

```
$uuids = [];
foreach($data AS $item) {
  $uuids[] = $item->uuid;
}

$uuids = implode(",", $uuids);
```

But in this method I am returning

```
"123-asdf,122-asfdsa,2323-aewrq"
```

But I need

```
'123-asdf','122-asfdsa','2323-aewrq'
```

If i do the above as string concatenation ie

```
$uuids = "";
foreach($data AS $item) {
  $uuids .= "'$item->uuid',";
}

$uuids = implode(",", $uuids);
```

I get

```
'\'123-asdf\',\'122-asfdsa\',\'2323-aewrq\'
```

Which again I cannot use for a SQL where statement. Does anybody have any tips to help please?

Comment: Don't do this in the first place. Use a prepared statement with parameters.

Comment: I've closed this as duplicates of questions that show how to do this in mysqli and PDO.